# Preserve trailing 0 with CDec

Tags: vb.net

I need to add a 0 if the value is a whole number and round to 1 decimal place if it already has decimal values.

I start with a String, convert with CDec, then round with Decimal.Round like this:

```
Decimal.Round(CDec(myText),1)
```

However, if myText is say, "1", I just get 1 out of this. From [documentation on CDec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx) I see that trailing 0's are not preserved unless arrived at computationally. How can I accomplish an explicit ".0" on a whole number?

Comment: what does it matter and how would your code detect a meaningless zero (e.g. `3.10` or `01.0`).  Are you really looking for a way to neaten output and make it uniform?

Comment: @Plutonix, it matters because the customer has required it. This is one  in a series of apps, and everywhere else (not using VB.NET) I am able to meet this requirement.

Comment: trailing zeros are not part of a value of a `Decimal`. 3.1000000 is the same.  Its only a matter of how you *format* your output

Comment: @hometoast, I would have been happy had someone helped me figure out how to format it (assuming formatting is even possible in this situation). Doing it mathematically is working well.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things people usually fail to understand is that how variables are stored internally is completely disassociated from how they may be displayed on the screen. The most common are date types and decimal types. The value of these variables may not be same as how they are displayed. e.g. dates are internally stored as decimals, while displayed in mm/dd/yyyy or other date formats. Similarly decimals are internally just pure decimal numbers (with no leading or trailing zeros or comma separators) while the displayed value can have the leading or trailing zeros and commas.

To format the display of your variables, call the `ToString()` method passing it the format you want to see.

In this case you would want to call `Decimal.ToString("0.0")` to round to one decimal place and force showing the trailing.

You can do one of the following:

```
DisplayText = CDec(myText).ToString("0.0")
```

Or,

```
DisplayText = Decimal.Parse(myText).ToString("0.0")
```

Comment: So if myText has more than 1 decimal, will this round it down correctly? The original question was about one aspect of the problem I am trying to solve; the solution cannot leave out the other aspect.

Comment: Yes, it will round it to one decimal place.

Comment: Won't always round down. It can be up or down depending on 2nd decimal place. Round up for more than 5; round down for less than 5. Same as `Round` function.

Comment: This might work: `code` Decimal.Round(CDec(myText)).ToString("0.0")

Comment: It does not work. It takes an existing value of 0.5 and turns it into 0.0.

Comment: What I meant by "round down" is round .15 and .25 correctly to .2 and .2 (down from more than one decimal place).

Comment: It is the same thing; it won't affect anything. `ToString("0.0")` would do the rounding same as how `Decimal.Round` would do.

Comment: It should work. Have a look at this msdn reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It needed "#" in the correct places. In the mean time, I accomplished the same thing with FormatNumber().

Comment: # is for optional digit. What I posted should have worked. Though I don't have a PC nearby to test.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
CDec(myText).ToString("0.0")
```

or this:

```
CDec(myText).ToString("N1")
```

See the references for [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) and [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) format strings. Variants of those that use overloads of [`Decimal.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `CDec()` are also okay.

Don't mess around with `Decimal.Round()` unless you need to [set the MidPoint Rounding Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y(v=vs.110).aspx), and don't mess around with `FormatNumber()`.

Answer (score -1):

IGear approves this approach; this seems to be working *and* stable:

```
FormatNumber(Decimal.Round(CDec(myText),1), 1, TriState.True, TriState.False, TriState.False)
```

Answer (score -2):

Exploiting the preservation of trailing 0 if it's computationally derived, I tried:

```
Decimal.Round((CDec(myText)+.0D,1)
```

This works without changing the value.

Comment: This is a terrible solution.  It relies on side-effects that may or may not be preserved in future updates/releases of vbc.  Additionally it obfuscates the purpose of the code.  There should be a clear demarkation between structure (value) and presentation.

Comment: Seriously: `CDec(myText).ToString("0.0")` will do what you want. Alternatively, `CDec(myText).ToString("N1")`. Don't mess around with `Decimal.Round()` unless you need a special rounding type, and don't mess around with `FormatNumber()`